Determining the major product in self aldol
I came across 2 conflicting sources of information. The 1st source claims the following:

Whereas the 2nd source claims the exact opposite. It states that in acidic medm the 1st cmpd is major and in basic medm 2nd cmpd in major.
Which one is correct?

The enolate that forms under thermodynamic conditions (heating) is the most substituted. So source 2 has to be correct.

I think that first source is correct.
First Reaction:
In the first reaction, the medium is basic. So, the $\ce{OH^-}$ will first attack the $\ce{\pi^*}$ of $\ce{C=O}$ bond, but since $\ce{-OH}$ is a leaving group, that step is reversible. Now, the $\ce{OH^-}$ will take $\ce{H^+}$ from the methyl ketone part, i.e. the left side of compound, so, a -ve charge will be developed there, which will resonate with $\ce{C=O}$. Now, the -ve charge on methyl ketone part will attack on $\ce{C=O}$ of another molecule, creating an aldol. Now, after heating this, the alcohol group of aldol, creating an alkene with IUPAC name as 5-Methylhept-4-en-3-one.
Second Reaction:
In the first reaction, the medium is acidic. So, the oxygen will the $\ce{H^+}$ and form $\ce{C=OH^+}$. Now, formation of enol takes place and it forms But-2-en-2-ol. Now, since $\ce{-OH}$ is electron donating group, it donates a lone pair to the carbon attached to it and the alkene on that carbon attacks $\ce{\pi^*}$ of $\ce{C=O}$ bond of another molecule and heat removes $\ce{-OH}$ creating an alkene. Hence, 2,3-Dimethylhex-3-en-2-one would be major product.
I hope this clears your doubt. This is what I think (I could be wrong as right now I am in high school and quite new to Organic Chemistry).
Please correct me if I am wrong in any step. I would be very thankful.

Base-catalyzed aldol condensation does not proceed by nucleophilic attack of the hydroxyl to the carbonyl carbon. It proceeds by the abstraction of a C-H proton at the  carbon, leading to a carbanion that forms the enolate. You are heating the system, so the thermodynamic enolate (the more substituted one) is greatly favored, which then attacks the carbonyl carbon of another butanone molecule, followed by the standard E1cB mechanism. Source 2 is correct (though both reactions should give you the same major product because of enolate/enol stability).

But since the carbanion has -ve charge stable on the left side, as if -ve charge is formed on right, an electron donating methyl group is present which will make it quite unstable. Hence I think the carbanion will be formed in left side, and formation of buten-2-ol takes place and then the alkene attacks to another molecule. Thats why I think both reactions will have different alkenes formed.

Enolates are resonance structures. The charge is delocalized over the oxygen, the carbonyl carbon and the  carbon, and the bonding between them can be thought of as an intermediate between single and double bonds. Double bonds at the more substituted carbon are always favored because of hyperconjugation, and while these are not double bonds in reality, they behave in similar ways. You will always favor the formation the thermodynamic enolate unless kinetic conditions (like cold temp. and a slight excess of a fast-acting bulky base) are put in place.

Oh yes! I just didn't saw that charge was delocalized over oxygen. Thank you for pointing out my mistake, so I think for both acidic and basic medium, second compound (2,3-Dimethylhex-3-en-2-one) would be major? Am I right?
